# jQuery infinite loop through each div

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop

I have some divs with divs in them, which I want to loop through while removing a class from the current one, then adding a class to the next one.

Then when I reach the last one, I want to go back to the start and do it all over again.

I already have a way of doing this, but it only works for one set of divs, I'm going to be having many sets of divs that need to loop independently.

Here's an example few sets (there would be a random amount of divs in each):

```
<div class="set">
    <div class="current">Item1</div>
    <div>Item2</div>
    <div>Item3</div>
</div>


<div class="set">
    <div class="current">Item1</div>
    <div>Item2</div>
    <div>Item3</div>
    <div>Item4</div>
    <div>Item5</div>
</div>
```

I need to remove that current class, and add it to the next div in each set, and so on.

Here is the code I have that works with one set:

```
$(function() {
    var items = $('.set div').length;
        current = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        $('.set div').eq(current).removeClass('current');

        if (current == items - 1){
            current = 0;
        } else {
            current++;
        }

        $('.set div').eq(current).addClass('current');
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: posting your current jquery code could help, if you already have a method for doing it to one set of divs using `each()` for all divs of class "set" should solve the problem, or am I mistaken?

Comment: would all parent divs have `class="set"`?  and when you say that you'll have "many sets of divs that need to loop independently" are you saying that while all sets have a parent div with `class="set"`, the number of sets `n` to work on would be anywhere from 1 to `n`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

my take:

http://jsfiddle.net/yyY28/

```
$('.set').each(function(){
    (function($set){
        setInterval(function(){
            var $cur = $set.find('.current').removeClass('current');
            var $next = $cur.next().length?$cur.next():$set.children().eq(0);
            $next.addClass('current');
        },1000);
    })($(this));

});​
```

---

version 2:

```
​setInterval(function(){
    $('.set').each(function(){
        var $cur = $(this).find('.current').removeClass('current');
        var $next = $cur.next().length?$cur.next():$(this).children().eq(0);
        $next.addClass('current');
    });
},1000);​
```

Comment: That works perfectly, and it's actually less code than my original. Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: You assign each `.set` a new `setInterval`, so in couple of minutes the sets will run out of synchronous work.

Comment: @VisioN good point. I added a second version which can't run out of sync and is more elegant as well. edit: oh it's almost exactly your version now :P

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't get you right, but is that you are looking for?

```
function loop() {
    $(".set").each(function() {
        var current = $(this).children(".current").removeClass("current");
        var i = current.next().length ? current.index() : 0;
        current.siblings(":eq(" + i + ")").addClass("current");
    });
}

setInterval(loop, 500);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jGcsh/

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
function changeCurrent(){
    $('.set').each(function(){
        var currentSubDiv = $(this).children('.current');
        currentSubDiv.removeClass('current');
        currentSubDiv.next().addClass('current');
    })
}

setInterval(changeCurrent,timeInMillis);
```